# Question on Baby Rudin 1.22 about decimal expansions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, approximation

In Baby Rudin 1.22 (Decimals):

We conclude this section by pointng out the relation between real numbers and decimals.
Let $x>0$ and $n_0$ be the largest integer such that $n_0\leq x$. (Note that the existence of $n_0$ depends on the Archimedean property of $\mathbb R$.) Having chosen $n_0,n_1,\dots,n_{k-1},$ let $n_k$ be the largest integer such that
$$n_0+\frac{n_1}{10}+\dots+\frac{n_k}{10^k}\leq x$$
Let E be the set of these numbers 
$$n_0+\frac{n_1}{10}+\dots+\frac{n_k}{10^k}$$

Here is my question:
I want to prove that $x=\sup E$.

$x \geq \sup E$ is explained easily, because x is upper bound of E from the definition, I wonder how we can get contradiction, if we suppose $x>\sup E$.

Comment: Suppose that set of numbers has a smaller upper bound y < x. Derive a contradiction.

Comment: Because I want to prove that $x=\sup E$, I think it is more proper to search a element of E is bigger than $\sup E$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly,
$$
x<n_0+1
$$
Inductively, one can similarly prove that
$$
x<n_0+\frac{n_1}{10}+\cdots+\frac{n_k+1}{10^k}
$$
thus
$$
x-\frac{1}{10^k}<n_0+\frac{n_1}{10}+\cdots+\frac{n_k}{10^k}\le \sup E,
$$
for all $k$, which implies that
$$
x\le \sup E.
$$